# str_replace with apostrophe

Tags: php, str-replace

I have the following word:

```
d\'b
```

and when I do the following:

```
$test = str_replace(array("\\", "'"), "", "d\'b");
```

the outcome is:

```
d'b
```

Any idea why the apostrophe is not being replaced?

Comment: may be this is the problem your php version because for me, it is working fine.

Comment: maybe the `'` is not a true apostrophe, perhaps a back-tick, urlencoded astrophe (%27) ?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Well, it works for me using the same version.

Comment: it def has to do with the version.  I just uploaded a similar example on my live server and it's working fine!

Comment: Maybe you have some html entity in your input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry everyone - my bad -.-

The string I had being posted through a form was already being passed through htmlentities so the only thing I had to do was:

```
 str_replace("&#039;", "", $variable);
```

I didn't realize it because when echoing the variable, it was being converted to the apostrophe

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$test = str_replace(array("\\'", "'"), "", "d\'b");
```

[Tested here](http://ideone.com/5x27X), seems to work well.

Comment: didn't work either :s - guess it has to do with the php version?

Answer (score 0):

Try to escape the backslash.. this worked for me

```
$test = str_replace(array("\\'", "'"), "", "d\'b");
```

Edit: pasted the wrong code.

Comment: You do not escape the apostroph but rather the backslash itself.

Comment: Yes, I suppose I mistyped that, ty :D

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
$test = str_replace(array("\\", "&#039;"), "", htmlspecialchars("d\'b", ENT_QUOTES));
```

May be it can help you.

Comment: the &#039; is not replaced no :/ wtf seriously!!